# What are the Mob Spawning Limits on Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

While playing Minecraft Xbox, I have created a mob tower with a grinder.

In thinking to minimize the impact of mobs spawning in random underground caves (or any other place that is not in the grinder), I created it over a body of water at a corner of the map.

However, after reading [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_spawning#Mob_spawning), I'm not so sure that this is the best course of action; given that mob limits are directly related to the chunks available for spawning.

My question is:

When calculating the maximum number of mobs on Xbox, does being near the edge of the map decrease these limits (as the wording would indicate), or does Xbox handle this in a different manner?

Comment: It's possible that this is only answerable (definitively) by someone with access to the code for Xbox Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it does matter. Since the number of chunks is NOT infinite like PC, then yes, being at the edge of the map reduces the number of mobs that can spawn. Although the algorithm for this uses an area of 17x17 chunks centred around the player, mobs can only spawn naturally within a 15x15 block area centred around the player. Limit= constant*chunks/256 . If you were at the corner, for example, the number of chunks eligible for spawning is only a quarter of the 17x17 chunk area

Comment: Sorry about that first answer. I mixed up PC and XBOX spawning rules

Comment: Do you have anything that can validate this claim?

Comment: Validate the algorithm or the actual answer?

Comment: Both are on the Wiki page that you linked, by the way

Comment: Mobs spawn naturally within a 15x15 chunk (240x240 block) area around the player.Mob caps are directly proportional to the total number of chunks eligible for spawning. To calculate the cap, the spawning area is expanded by one chunk in every direction, so that it is 17x17 chunks in size, and then the total number of chunks is plugged into the following formula:
 cap = constant * chunks / 256-http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Mob_spawning#Mob_spawning

Comment: So basically it takes a 17x17 chunk area around you ( with you at its centre) checks how many of those are eligible for spawning( i.e subtracts the number of chunks outside the map and chunks in mushroom biomes), and uses the number of remaining chunks to calculate the mob limit for where you are standing

Comment: Yes, I read all that on the wiki page (linked in the question). My question: does the lack of chunks play into the spawning caps (as the wiki alludes to), or does it ignore that there are no chunks there, because it is based off a game that has no real limit of chunks. You say that the lack of chunks reduces the maximum. While I concede that this is a possible answer (again, in the question), my question to you is why did you reach this conclusion? Did you reach this by reading the wiki (a logical, but biased conclusion), or did you see some other post that authenticates it?

Comment: I will test it out on a superflat world.I'll make two platforms; one at the edge and one dead-center, light up the rest and leave it for an hour each and compare the results. I;ll post my findings :D

Comment: @KrymeX Any findings yet?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter. If you were making a mob grinder in open world, flat if it suits you, and at the edge of the map. It makes absolutely no diff. Yes they naturally spawn in a 17X17 chunk surrounding and spawn in more frequently inside that range but at a distance greater than 25+ blocks away.

What these guys forget to tell you is that if the only available chunks to spawn in are in your mob tower then they will spawn with max efficiency if the tower is dark (below light level 4). Xbox spawn ability just blows. That is why we get such low item counts.

So in short, No, your corner does not impede mob spawn ability/efficiency given that the other 8 1/2 X 8 1/2 chunks are lit, full of water or to a height that does not allow mob spawn. ie-126 and above for all 2 block high mobs or 127 to get rid of any 1 block high mobs like spiders. And to increase any further you would need to get the ceiling at 127-Y and work your way down keeping yourself as far away from any land mass to avoid spawning in caves etc. Again, if you are in flat world this becomes quite easy to accomplish.